# django POST [Legitimacy]

Tags: django

Lets say I have a web application that displays 2 random buttons on each session, and I want the user to click on 1 button or the other. If a button is clicked, I want to increment the score for that button. However, the user has no control on what 2 buttons are presented each time and there are thousands of possible buttons.

If I create a view to increment the button, how would I be sure that the user wont just manually go to that view through the browser.

My thoughts are that you need to create a form and have users POST to a certain address, but how do you know that the user didn't just send a post request through AJAX to increment the button and that the user actually received that button from the randomized session with 2 buttons.

How would I handle this in Django is there documentation detailing how Django specifically supports this?

EDIT: Or do you have to create a unique session ID for each button selecting session and check each button click against the unique session ID.

Answer (score 0):

Create a session variable to track the button they see, like:

```
def button_display_view(request):
    # ...lots of cool logic
    session['buttons_shown'] = [button_1_primary_key, button_2_primary_key]
    return response
```

Then, in your button click view, ensure that the button clicked was in the list of buttons that they were shown. The user will have zero knowledge of your session variable, nor be able to edit it, much like he/she can't when you use session variables to track authentication, etc.

If you're building a multivariate testing system (or even an AB testing system), it might be worth checking out [this MVT app](https://github.com/ubiquitousthey/django-mvtester) for ideas.